# Looking for a command to check for on-chip L3 cache size on a Unix system

Tags: unix, cache

I am looking for a command to check for on-chip L3 cache size on a Unix system.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at dmidecode, which has an excellent man page.

Look for an entry named "Processor Information", mine reads:

```
Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    ...
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0008
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0009
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    ...
```

This tells me to look for the handle 0x0009 (for L2 cache, since I don't have any L3). This reads:

```
Handle 0x0009, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: External
    Installed Size: 2048 KB
    Maximum Size: 2048 KB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Burst
        Pipeline Burst
        Asynchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Burst
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Unknown
    System Type: Unknown
    Associativity: Unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

On recent Linux kernels running on the x86 architecture, you can probably find the information you want at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu#/cache` (replace the `#` by the CPU number). For instance, on this computer (which does not have a L3 cache):

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/level 
1
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/type 
Data
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/size 
64K
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/level
1
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/type 
Instruction
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/size 
64K
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/level 
2
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/type 
Unified
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/size 
512K
```

This corresponds to a L1 data cache of 64K, a L1 instruction cache of 64K, and a L2 instruction+data cache of 512K. Note that this is more detailed than `/proc/cpuinfo`, which only says `cache size   : 512 KB`. There are several other files in these `cache/index#` directories with even more detail.

Please read `Documentation/ABI/README` and `Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu` before using these files; in particular, they do not seem to be a stable ABI, and thus might become missing in the future. They come from `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/intel_cacheinfo.c`, which uses `cpuid` to directly get the information (meaning that, when present, they should be more reliable than `dmidecode`).

Answer (score 1):

look at '/proc/cpuinfo'

Comment: Doesnt help - here is the output of the command:
processor  : 7
vendor     : GenuineIntel
arch       : IA-64
family     : Itanium 2
model      : 2
revision   : 1
archrev    : 0
features   : branchlong
cpu number : 0
cpu regs   : 4
cpu MHz    : 1500.000000
itc MHz    : 1500.000000
BogoMIPS   : 2239.75
siblings   : 1

Comment: Also procfs is a Linux (not UNIX) thing and FreeBSD for example only has it with the Linux-compat installed.

Comment: I thought it was a Unix thing, it's been 10 years since I last worked with commercial Unix (I miss Sun).
On my Pentium and Core Duo it tells you cache. On an Itanium you probably have to pay extra to find it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, just use /proc/cpuinfo or any other method to find the model number of your processor, and look that up on google to find the specs.